# jquery accordion with responsive image maps

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perhaps the answer is already here someplace, but I can't find it.. I tried, I really did.

Using Jquery accordion to toggle between 2 different image maps, which happen to be actual maps of USA and Canada. The site is also responsive, so using the "Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin"  from http://mattstow.com/

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h2>UNITED STATES</h2>
    <div class="center-text">
        <img src="usa.jpg" height="420" width="574"  usemap="#map" />
        <map name="map">
            <area shape="circle" coords="479, 159, 10" href="/MD/"/>
            <area shape="circle" coords="487, 126, 10" href="/NJ/"/>
            ....
        </map>
    </div>

    <h2>CANADA</h2>
    <div class="center-text">
        <img src="canada.jpg" width="574" height="300"  usemap="#map2" />
        <map name="map2">
            <area shape="poly" coords="196, 94, 240, 100, 236, 217, 175, 210" href="/SK/" alt="SK"/>
            <area shape="circle" coords="552, 193, 13" href="/NS/" alt="NS"/>
            ...
        </map>
    </div>

    ....

    <script src="/jquery/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

The problem...
On the initial page load, it works as expected.. The 1st accordian is expanded, showing the US map and the links work.

However if you click to expand the "Canada" accordian, the links do not work at all.. as if you are simply clicking a plain image.

Resizing the browser window will make the Canada image map work, presumably because this triggers the responsive image map plugin. BUT, if you re-open the USA accordian, now it has no links, until you resize the window browser again (eg; trigger the function again).

There must be a way to call that function when an accordian is expanded .. I'm just not a javascript kinda guy. Gentle taps with cluestick would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's accordiOn, not accordiAn

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I'm not a fiddle user (I suppose I should be) but you can see the scenario I describe on a site here     http://www.your-realtypro.com/

Comment: I apparently missed the oppurtunity to edit my question.. I wanted to add the website where you can see the issue.. it's at  http://your-realtypro.com